# What instruction is more efficient?

Tags: performance, concurrency, parallel-processing

I have the following function inside a .cpp file which `#include`s "IonizationTables.h", the .h file where the vector `ionizationEnergy[100*101/2]` is implemented (as a look-up table) with 5050 (double) entries:, and also `#include`s "Ionization.h", where `eV_to_au` is defined and which is then implemented in Ionization.cpp, as a double value (`double eV_to_au = 1.0 / 27.2116;`).

```
double continuity_tool(double Potential, unsigned int atomic_number_, unsigned int Z) {
   double Potential_in_eV = Potential / eV_to_au; // a division
   double Potential_in_eVV = IonizationTables::ionizationEnergy[atomic_number_*(atomic_number_-1)/2 + Z]; // equivalent to above. which is more efficient?
}
```

I have to call this function for more than 100.000 times in a simulation, possibly millions.

The simulation is done on a HPC cluster, with many many nodes and cores.

How shall I calculate Potential in eV? Using first instruction or using 2nd instruction? And why?

Thank you!

Comment: Division by a dynamic number or a constant that's not power of two will probably be several times slower than a table lookup, but you should be able to measure that for yourself.

Comment: Why to divide by 1.0/27.2116 instead of to multiply by 27.2116? Division is much slower than multiplication. A compiler may do this optimization for you under some circumstances (`-ffast-math`), but only if it sees the value of `eV_to_au` in the same translation unit.

Comment: Have you tried to compare both options and measure? What were the results? This question is quite generic. For instance, the outcome may heavily result on how you use this function. If this use is SIMD-friendly, then this may make the calculation-based option more beneficial.

Comment: This is not so much a question about C++ or any programming language, but about the underlying hardware. Please, adjust the tags accordingly.

Comment: Regarding the question, if you can convert the division to multiplication by a reciprocal, then that will likely be the fastest option on modern CPUs and GPUs. Table lookup can be fast, but its efficiency largely depends on your working set. If you have lots of data to process then you may be short on cache capacity, which makes tables less efficient. In general - pure computational resources tend to be cheaper than memory or storage bandwidth.

Comment: Thank you to all! The HPC code documentation says it uses SIMD vectorization, if this helps. I thought my q is an easy one with a particular answer, I didn't know it depends on the underlying hardware.